# Pyads connection refused with Beckhoff running Twincat 3

Tags: linux, plc, twincat

I am trying to make a connection from a server running Ubuntu to a Beckhoff PLC with TwinCAT 3. With Windows everything works fine but with the same server on Linux I can't get a connection.

The Linux server has a static IP and in the route manager in the PLC I can find the route and see the server. I have tried adding the route by the route manager in the PLC and with "add_route_to_plc" but both ways my connection is refused. I have already turned off all firewalls. Any of you guys any idea what goes wrong here? In the attachment I have added some picture to see my settings and code that I try to run.

Python error: "connection closed by remote"

Python code:

```py
import pyads

SENDER_AMS = '192.168.1.180.1.1'
PLC_IP = '192.168.1.100'
PLC_USERNAME = 'Administrator'
PLC_PASSWORD = '1'
ROUTE_NAME = 'GID_TEST_ROUTE'
HOSTNAME = 'Grid-stabilizer'

pyads.open_port()
pyads.set_local_address(SENDER_AMS)
pyads.add_route_to_plc(SENDER_AMS, HOSTNAME, PLC_IP, PLC_USERNAME, PLC_PASSWORD, route_name=ROUTE_NAME)
pyads.close_port()

plc=pyads.Connection('192.168.1.100.1.1', pyads.PORT_TC3PLC1)
plc.open()
plc.read_state()
```

Comment: Why do you do `pyads.close_port()` before making a connection to the PLC? If without that is doesn´t work, try out the exact [example from the pyads docs](https://pyads.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Comment: I already tried the code from that manual and some youtube videos. I will try it without closing the port, but I think that doesn't matter because in the code above I only make a new route in the PLC itself, that is something you only need to do once.

Comment: Just checked if it works without closing the port, unfortunately the same result

Comment: I'm confused. You say it works but gives the same result, which implies a connection closed by remote.

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.twincontrols.com/community/twincat-knowledgebase/connecting-to-twincat-using-python/#post-320) can also help you.

Comment: To clarify, with or without closing the port, I get the same error, and that is: "Connection closed by remote"

Comment: I was thinking because it works on Windows just fine and not in Ubuntu it is maybe a version issue. Are there any version issues known with Linux and Pyads and Beckhoff?

Comment: I would say make and issue at the pyads repo, but I guess this is you https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads/issues/333

Answer (score 1):

If you are running python on linux and the plc on windows try

```
plc=pyads.Connection('192.168.1.100.1.1', pyads.PORT_TC3PLC1, PLC_IP)
```

This will create a route on the linux system. In your code the ip is missing to create a proper route.

Check the port of your plc. It should be 851.